# What does the $ mean in this jquery autocomplete example

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

what does it mean by the $.ui... in the following jquery autocomplete example and what is .bind is doing?
and also i'm not getting the bind part (about how it's working) of this example. please help

(this is the direct example of the jquery autocomplete ui)

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        function split( val ) {
          return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
          return split( term ).pop();
        }

        $( "#birds" )
          // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
          .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&     // WHAT DOES THE $ MEAN HERE
                $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          })
          .autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
              $.getJSON( "search.php", {
                term: extractLast( request.term )
              }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
              // custom minLength
              var term = extractLast( this.value );
              if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                return false;
              }
            },
            focus: function() {
              // prevent value inserted on focus
              return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
              var terms = split( this.value );
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push( ui.item.value );
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push( "" );
              this.value = terms.join( ", " );
              return false;
            }
          });
      });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
  <input id="birds" size="50">
</div>
```

Comment: [.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) - event registration method

Comment: `$.ui.keyCode` - here `$` refers to the jQuery object and `$.ui` includes some of the static helper methods provided by jQuery UI

Comment: i meant what is this function doing on bind

Comment: it is checking whether the pressed key is the `TAB` key or not... `event.keyCode` will contain the code for the currently pressed key and `$.ui.keyCode.TAB` is a constant for the tab key code